# How can I add extension to Task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

When creating Gradle plugin you can extend the DSL with own extension object but from the documentation I see that the **DefaultTask** implements **ExtensionAware** interface too.

[image]

So I want to ask:

1. How can I add extension to task?
2. In what situations I have to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a extra property to a task using the `ext` namespace. It's usually used to enrich Gradle's domain model (like tasks) with new properties or methods. Let's say you wanted to add an extra property to the task `myTask`:

```
task myTask {
    ext.myProp = 'hello world'

    doLast {
        println myProp
    }
}

assert myTask.myProp == 'hello world'
myTask.myProp = 'new value'
assert myTask.myProp == 'new value'
```

You can see here that you can directly access and modify this property in the context of the task.

Comment: So Extra properties are extensions for the task? Do I understand correctly? And when I am creating Custom Task can I use ExtentionContainer.create to add extra Properties to it?